# Inverse function with two $x$'s

Tags: inverse-function

In  the case of the function $f(x)=x^2+x^4$ is there any trick to inversing it? as the only ways I know do not work on it. As you cannot make y the subject through rearranging it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's quadratic in $u=x^2$.

Comment: Can you solve a quadratic equation? Since you have an even function here, you will get multiple possible values for the inverse. Do you have a protocol for choosing which you want?

Comment: In general, no there is no trick to finding the inverse. One idea is to exchange $y$ and $x$. In your example you would
$$ x = y^2 + y^4 $$
and solve for $y$, this would be your inverse.

Comment: ah thank you, I did not even think of that.

Comment: This function doesn't have a unique inverse (assuming that the domain is the set of all real numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Setting $$y=x^2+x^4$$ we get
$$x^4+x^2-y=0$$ solving this using the quadratic formula we obtain
$$x^2_{1,2}=-\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+y}$$
can you go on?

Comment: the thing is, I never done inverse with quadratics before, so the whole thing in general is new ,but thanks